# very simple Pine Script error : cannot call strategy argument

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Trend Trailing" , overay=false, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_value=3, precision=4, initial_capital=17000, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, default_qty_value=1)

EntryLine = ((close[2] + close[1] + close)/3)-((close[2]+close[1])/2)*100/ close[2]

LongLine= 0.05

if (crossover(EntryLine,LongLine))
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true, qty=1)

strategy.exit(id="OL", from_entry="EL", qty=1, trail_points=0.3)
```

What's wrong in this script?
I'm a newbie at pine script..

Comment: If there's a stack trace or any other information about the error (particularly what line it's happening on), please include that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the parameter `overlay`.